# What does onChange in html convert to Angular look like?

Tags: angular

I have a 'span' that will display when an 'h2' value equal null and disappear when 'h2' value not null. I tried implement OnChanges so they will track each other value.

My ts

```
remindNotify(){
    var x = document.getElementById("notifyTitle");
    var y = document.getElementById("badge");
    if(x == null){
      y.style.display= "block";
    }else{
      y.style.display= "none";
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void{
    this.remindNotify();
  }
```

My html

```
<span id="badge">#</span>
<h2 id="notifyTitle" >{{ (message | async)?.notification.title }}</h2>
```

Comment: Don't do that. Just `<span *ngIf="(message | async)?.notification.title == null" id="badge">#</span>`

Comment: @ritaj Thank you sir.